# How can I remove comments on-fly from my static CSS files?

Tags: java, css, facelets

I'm using facelets, and I have a number of CSS files in `webapp/styles/blueprint/*.css`. They contain comments which I don't want to become visible to end-users. How can I remove them on-fly?

Comment: Is minifying your CSS as part of the build an option?  Doing something once for the same result is infinitely more efficient than doing it on every request of the CSS.

Comment: @Nick, yes, I agree, it's an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/). It will not only remove comments, but also minify the CSS (and JS) files.

```
Reader reader = null;
Writer writer = null;

try {
    reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(cssFile), "UTF-8");
    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(minFile), "UTF-8");
    new CssCompressor(reader).compress(writer, -1); // That's it.
} finally {
    close(writer);
    close(reader);
}
```

#### See also

- [Webapplication performance tips and tricks](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/09/webapplication-performance-tips-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Nick Craver said in the comments, you should, if at all, do that work as a part of your building process since css is a static resource. No runtime modifications needed.

Now depending on your build process, you could write a small script that simply strips out any comments, my first approach would be regular expressions:

```
cssFileContents = cssFileContents.replaceAll("/\*.*?\*/", ""); //with lazy quantifier on the "."!
```

In this case you need to make sure that the regex "."-metacharacter includes linebreaks.

Since css only allows block comments (/* ... */) and no line comments (// ... \n), this is the only thing you need to replace.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks! But I thought that maybe there are some libraries exist, which automate the process and do some extra work. For example, optimizing of CSS and compressing it..